# How to make gpg find gpg-agent

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

On Fedora 22, gpg doesn't find gpg-agent:

```
% gpg-agent --daemon                                           

% gpg -vvv --use-agent --no-tty --decrypt file.gpg 
gpg: using character set `utf-8'
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid 3060B8F7271AFBAF
  data: [4094 bits]
gpg: public key is 271AFBAF
gpg: using subkey 271AFBAF instead of primary key 50EA64D5
gpg: using subkey 271AFBAF instead of primary key 50EA64D5
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Looking at the versions reveals the problem:

```
% gpg-agent --version
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.7

% gpg --version                                                               
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.19
```

The components come from different packages (`gnupg2-2.1.7-1.fc22.x86_64` and
`gnupg-1.4.19-2.fc22.x86_64` in my case). The solution is to use the `gpg2`
command instead of `gpg`.

Comment: thanks. i spent 30 minutes on the internet trying to figure out this stuff... turns out that most documentation and instructions do not take into account the breakage between versions of the tools. i was having to type in my passphrase for every run of gpg on 20 files i wanted to sign, now i can just do it once. thanks again.

Comment: this is still relevant with Fedora 27; using `gpg2` also enables the gnome integration

Answer (score 8):

In case it's helpful for some, `gpg` 1.4 can work just fine with `gpg-agent` 2.1.

When looking into it, I found this post: https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2014-October/029024.html

The agent is compatible, but no longer exports the environment variables that the older version of gpg expects. If you set those manually it will just work:

`export GPG_AGENT_INFO=${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1`

Comment: Fedora uses different default socket path. I had to use `GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/$(id -u)/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1` instead.